# " If the parent has no constructor (Object does have one), the compiler will reject the program."

Tags: java, object

Hi I was reading [Object declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), and encountered the statement

> If the parent has no constructor (Object does have one), the
> compiler will reject the program.

Does any one have any idea what this means?

Comment: Where did you read this? Can you quote a larger section?

Comment: This is very unclear. In fact, you cannot have a class without a constructor. Either you provide one explicit constructor, or - if you don't - the compiler will add an implicit no-arg constructor for you. One issue: This compiler-added no-arg constructor will implicitly call `super()` - the no-arg constructor of the parent class. That means, this parent class _must have_ such a no-arg constructor. If it hasn't, this is a compiler error.

Comment: I've encounter this too, and from the question discussion I said, maybe the meaning is: "if the parent has no-args constructor (because it's have other constructor, and then it's not inherit from Object the no-args constructor) the compiler will reject the program."

Answer (score 3):

It's nonsense. It is not possible to have a class in Java without a constructor.
What I assume you mean is: if there is no default constructor in the parent class.

The constructor of a child class will (as first statement) call the default constructor of the parent class. If that is not there, you will have to add an explicit call with the arguments to match the constructor that is there.

```
public class Parent{
  public Parent(String o){}
}

public class Child extends Parent{
  public Child(String o){}
}
```

Will not compile. The Child constructor will look for the default constructor of Parent, which isn't there. (It doesn't matter whether the constructor of Child has parameters, by the way).

So, you'll explicitly need to call the parents constructor:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent(String o) {
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(String o) {
    super(o);
    }
}
```

If Child had only a default constructor, it would be like this:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
    super(null);
    }
}
```

note: null could also be replaced by any valid (hardcoded) String value.

Comment: Thanks, actually line in quotes are from doc.oracle.com....I tried to compile ur codes and found that
if in parent class (super class) we are declaring any argument constructor then explicitly we need to declare default constructor else it won't compile.

Comment: unless you also declare a non-argument constructor, yes. By default, the first statement run by any constructor is: super(); ..
if there is no non-argument constructor in the parent class, this can't execute. It's the same as calling a method that doesn't' exist: compile time error.

Comment: code will compile if there is no non-argument constructor in parent class. there is reason as well, as each class implicitly extends Object class which has non-argument class declared. You can check below code its compiling
class Point
{
 public void display(){}
}
public class No_Cons_Parent extends Point
{
 public No_Cons_Parent() {}
 public static void main(String [] args){}
}

Comment: So ... both of them have a non-argument constructor, so, what is your point? The code would also compile and work if the constructor of the subclass would take arguments.

Comment: yep....that is right ....subclass constructor type doesn't effect the compilation ....its parent class one which has impact on compilation...argument constructor need to be accompanied with non-argument constructor (default)...to compile the code....

Answer (score 1):

> If the parent has no constructor (Object does have one), the compiler will reject the program

I think the basis is of your misunderstanding is that you are *thinking* that constructors are inherited.  In fact, constructors are **NOT** inherited in Java.  So consider the following example:

```
public class A {
    public A(int i) { super(); ... }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() { super(); ... }
}
```

The class `A`:

- does not inherit any constructors from `Object`,
- does not explicitly declare a no-args constructor (i.e. `public A() {...}`), and
- does not have a default constructor (since it *does* declare another constructor).

It has one and only one constructor: `public A(int)`.

It is not necessary for a constructor to *explicitly* call a superclass constructor.  But a lot of people think it is good style to include an explicit call.  If you leave it out, the Java compiler inserts an implicit call to the superclasses no-args constructor ... **and that results in a compilation error if the no-args constructor does not exist or is not visible to the subclass.**